# Elasticsearch search word

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, elastic4s

I have match queries:
`matchQuery("name", name) analyzer n gram min=2 max=3
matchQuery("allName", name) analyzer n gram min=3 max=6`

Most of them queries is almost true but the problem when I have documents like `dak abc,dave abc, dave dave def`. When I search "da", "dave dave def" should come first since term frequency 2 but it comes almost at the end.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If I omit field norm, the result will be what I want.